# dropdown list not shown

Tags: magento2, dropdown-attribute, drop-downs

I have a store in 2 languages. i create attribute Input Type for Store Owner is Dropdown. the list of choices are shown and work very well in store of English language but store in other language  not work and list doesn't appear. why? how can i solve it ? i work on magento 2 [image]
[image]

Comment: Just a thought but did you render the static content of your other stores?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your attribute for all stores or Global in **Scope** configuration.

- **Attribute Code** : The name of the attribute that will be used by the system
- **Scope** : allows you to declare the attribute value saving scope like
- **Website** : the value of this attribute for a product can be different in different Websites but have to stay the same between Store Views contained under the same Website.
- **Store View** : the value of this attribute for a product can be different in all Websites and all Store Views
- **Website** : the value of this attribute for a product can be different in different Websites but have to stay the same between Store Views contained under the same Website
- **Global** : the value of this attribute for a product must be the same for all websites and stores

For more [informations](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/product-attributes)

Comment: it's global for all stores

Comment: is there a solve for this problem???

Comment: Recheck all that i gave you, save and reindexall, clear also the cache.

Comment: it's not working , is it from programming of theme